# VBA: How to get current region from filtered data?

Tags: vba, excel, range, filtering, variant

I want to figure out how I can get data after filtering to variant object. When I use this:

```
table = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
```

I'm gettig all data but I want only filtered.

Workbooks screen shot:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` to get the filtered rows:

```
Dim Tbl As Range

Set Tbl = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
' for DEBUG onlu
Debug.Print Tbl.Address
```

---

**Edit 1**: Full code

```
Option Explicit

Sub VarfiltRange()

Dim BasketCostFiltRng As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim VarRes As Double

With Worksheets("Sheet1") '< -- modift "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get only the filteres rows in column D
    Set BasketCostFiltRng = .Range("D2:D" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    ' get the variance of only visible cells in Column "D" (after you filter to show only 1100 and 1112 in column "A")
    VarRes = WorksheetFunction.Var(BasketCostFiltRng)
    MsgBox VarRes
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ok and now I have object which contains every information of this Cells, how I can get value? I need this data to calculate variance of each month.

Comment: @KamilZawistowski   You can read it into an array, but for that you need to share your worksheets data, so we can understand better

Comment: drive.google.com/open?id=0B5PmrbRk4Uarai1fQk9SLWNrb1U there you have example workbook. Let's say that I want filer customer no. 1126 and 1100 in ,,Zakupy'' worksheet and then I want to calculate variance of basket cost.

Comment: @KamilZawistowski this is not how it works on **SO**, you can share a screen-shot of your relevant data to your post.

Comment: @KamilZawistowski  so which column from your data you want to calculate the variance ?

Comment: Column D but only for customer no 1100 and 1112.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `SpecialCells` to get that:

```
Sheet1.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
```

Comment: Just a few seconds after me... you were lurking for this one ;)